# Detect open AC circuit and fire alarm

Tags: design

I’m a noob, would appreciate any help with the following:

THE PROBLEM
We live on a mountain in North Carolina. When the temperature drops well below freezing, the well head freezes resulting in loss of water and broken pipes. I installed pipe heater tape which worked well for several years, but the tape burnt out and well head froze again. Many $$$ to repair.

THE QUESTION
Build a circuit that will:
1.  The easy part… turn heater on when thermocouple is closed, turn heater off when thermocouple is open. 
2.  The hard part… when heater is OFF, monitor the circuit so that if the heater is open, an alarm will sound.

The problem is that if the heater fails (burns out) at 3 am, you don’t know about it until too late. After 4 days of head scratching, I came up with the attached circuit using several relays. I’m not sure this will work, I think the heater will still run when K2 is fired, and the alarm will be on anytime the thermocouple is open.… All commercial products are designed to thermostatically control a heater. 
Looking at some circuits on Stack, it seems the best approach is a small current across the heater when it is off, then sound alarm when open is detected??

Help appreciated in advance…
**[image: strong text]**

Comment: Does a noob know how to crop? Or use the built in schematic editor?

Comment: could you just take a supply from mid-point of the heater element   to control (hold open) a relay that when closed sounds the alarm? this way if either the element fails or the supply to it fails then the alarm sounds... Will need a suitable relay for the voltage seen at that point...

Comment: The circuit won't work. Wouldn't it be easier to just put a temperature alarm at the well head? If heater fails, temp goes too low and alarm goes off? If you want a head start and detect an open heater, you can use a current transformer to detect that there is current flowing. Can't really do it with relays that I can think off. See http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transformer/current-transformer.html

Comment: I'm thinking current transformer, burden, diode bridge, comparator and an AND gate with your control signal and you should be good to go.

Comment: @HarrySvensson, let's be fair and welcoming here, a 'noob' wouldn't have the privileges to use the built-in schematic editor

Comment: Didn't mean to offend, I could not get Circuit Lab to open... used TinyCad and could not crop image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpYejo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Monitoring continuity of the tape wiring.*

The tape I'm familiar with has copper conductors with a "poor" insulation between the wires. This circuit monitors continuity of the copper. RLY2 should energise anytime RLY1 is on. If RLY2 does not energise then sound the alarm.

Your original question, however, doesn't indicate what the nature of the burn-out was: failed conductors or loss of conductance between the wires.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffXpkx.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Current monitoring.*

This circuit uses a current monitoring relay. If RLY1 turns on but there isn't enough current to turn on RLY2 then the alarm sounds.

Notes:

- Both circuits will give a brief alarm circuit closure while RLY1 is energised and RLY2 is responding.
- The circuits can be combined to use current monitoring and continuity monitoring.

[image]

*Figure 3. A simple current monitoring relay.*

A quick image search showed up the relay above. It is rated for 1 A through the coil. Note the few thick coil windings clearly visible in the photo.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdMSXC.png)</sup>

*Figure 4. Low-voltage permanent power.*

Since neither of the above really do what you asked for I offer Figure 4 as a low-voltage power monitoring solution. A transformer provides, say, 12 V supply to the heater when off. A ten times more sensitive current relay can monitor this current and alarm if the current falls below the threshold.

Points to note:

- Relays exhibit hysteresis. Once the relay energises it will remain energised until the current falls perhaps to half. This may be too late for your application.
- You can combine any variety of the above circuits.
- It would be more normal to put the thermostats in the live rather than neutral side of the relay.

Thermocouples:

- Theremocouples don't work as you have drawn them. You probably mean a thermostat as shown in my schematics.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a good attempt but wont work because AC input to the power supply  has an unknown yet relatively high impedance compared to the 25W heater, so current will be limited.

It would be far better to ensure there are no air gaps in the heater tape to ensure solid thermal conductance to the metal pipes.  Otherwise self-heating and heater temp rise and failure will occur.  Hot pipes are usually insulated with slit foam tubing inside homes to reduce hot water losses. Something like this may also help.

I would expect pipe heaters to use high current (15A) with low voltage and then insulated pipes with insulated wire would operate at lower voltage and could withstand more gap tolerance.